# Firebase function runs extremely slow

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a firebase function that uses a storage trigger to populate the firestore database for an uploaded csv file. I used and npm package csvtojson to do the conversion from csv to json. The problem is the function runs extremely slow. To be precise it takes a very long time for the data to be reflected in the firestore. There are cases where it doesn't reflect at all. The function is below. Is there a way I can make this faster?

```
exports.fillDatabaseCSV = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async (object) => {
    try {
      // File and directory paths.
      const filePath = object.name;
      const contentType = object.contentType;
      const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
      const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
      const fileBasename = path.basename(filePath);

      // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
      if (contentType !== "text/csv") {
        return console.log("This is not a csv file");
      }

      // Cloud Storage files.
      const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
      const file = bucket.file(filePath);

      // Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
      await mkdirp(tempLocalDir);

      // Download file from bucket.
      await file.download({ destination: tempLocalFile });
      console.log("The csv file has been downloaded to", tempLocalFile);

      //uses csvtojson
      const jsonArray = await csv().fromFile(tempLocalFile);

      let firestorePromise = [];

      jsonArray.forEach(async (item) => {
        let user = await admin.auth().createUser({
          email: item.email,
          password: item.password,
          displayName: item.displayName,
        });

        firestorePromise.push(
          admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.toJSON().uid).set({
            email: item.email,
            displayName: item.displayName,
            role: item.role,
          })
        );

        if (item.role !== "normal") {
          let claims = {};
          claims[item.role] = true;
          firestorePromise.push(
            admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.toJSON().uid, claims)
          );
        }
      });

      await Promise.all(firestorePromise);
      //delete temp and file itself
      fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
      await file.delete();
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
```

Comment: You're performing a `createUser()` operation for each line in the CSV file, of course it's going to take a while.

Comment: Is there a way I make the function faster??

Comment: The users are created almost instantly. It is the firestore writes that delays

Comment: You need to use bathed write

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 1):

Your functions is dependent on operations from Firestore, Cloud Storage, and Firebase Auth.  The products and APIs will always do what they do, and can't be sped up, in a general sense.

Firestore is [limited](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) to 500 writes per second per collection "in which documents contain sequential values in an indexed field".  You might be coming up against this limit.  It's a hard limit and can't be increased.  If this is the limiting factor, the best you can do is consider some of the advice in the [best practices documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range), including [index exemptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#index_exemptions) for problematic fields in your documents.